# How to correctly use ARC with interfaces?

Tags: delphi, interface, automatic-ref-counting

I have a problem understanding how ARC with Interfaces exactly work. In most tutorials I have read that setting the interface to nil will call `_Release`, which will call `Destroy`, when the ARC counter reaches zero. I have read a few tutorials, but it is not yet clear to me.

```
type
  IXXX = interface(IInterface)
  end;

  TXXX = class(TInterfacedPersistent, IXXX)
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;


procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  intf: IXXX;
begin
  intf := TXXX.Create; // IntfCopy  will be called. Message "create"
  intf := nil;         // IntfClear will be called. No message "destroy"
end;

{ TXXX }

constructor TXXX.Create;
begin
  inherited;

  showmessage('create');
end;

destructor TXXX.Destroy;
begin
  showmessage('destroy');

  inherited;
end;
```

When I run this program, I will get a message "create", but no message "destroy". I have looked in the assembler code and saw that calls to `System._IntfCopy` and `System._IntfClear` are made.

Looking into `System._IntfClear` makes clear that `_Release` is not called when `Source` is nil, which is true for `intf := nil`. So there is no wonder why the object is never destroyed.

But how to use ARC correctly then?

[A blog](http://blogs.encodo.ch/news/view_article.php?id=11) recommends not touching interfaces and instead using only non-reference-counted versions. I know how to override `_AddRef` and `_Release` for bypassing/disabling ARC, but I want to use ARC, except if there is a good reason not to use it.

(Using Delphi 6)

Comment: You say using Delphi 6 -- I assume you mean Delphi XE6 since Delphi 6 does not support ARC, only interface reference counting.

Comment: I meant Delphi 6. With "Interface ARC" I meant ARC for interfaces. I know that normal objects do not have ARC/GC in Delphi 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class you derive from, `TInterfacedPersistent` has this to say in its [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TInterfacedPersistent):

> TInterfacedPersistent, like all persistent objects, supports the ability to read and write its properties to and from a stream. In addition, it supplies a default implementation of the IInterface methods (_AddRef, _Release, and QueryInterface). This default implementation simply passes these calls on to the interface of the persistent object's Owner, if any.

The call to `_Release` is of course made when the reference count drops to zero. But nothing happens then because your object has no owner.

If you wish to use reference counting to manage the lifetime then you should dervive from `TInterfacedObject` instead. Or provide implementations of `_AddRef` and `_Release` that count references and destroy the object when the reference count drops to zero. Use `TInterfacedObject` as the template of how to implement that.

For what it is worth, the article you link to contains stunningly bad advice. Do not heed it. If you are to use interfaces, let reference counting manage lifetime, and refer to the objects only through interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the actual problem. I noticed that my example above works with `TInterfacedObject`, so I was searching at the wrong place all the time to find the memory leak. I use `TInterfacedPersistent` in my project, since I want to be able to copy the object's contents using `Assign` (so I override `AssignTo`). Now I see that I also need to override `GetOwner` to have ARC working. But what do I do when I do not have a parent-owner-structure - simply a persistent object which I want to copy? Should GetOwner then always return Self?

Comment: But you are then going to break the "all or nothing" rule of ARC. Either be ARC all the way, or not at all. And to use ARC you need to avoid any references other than via interfaces.

Comment: Uh, ok. I think I misunderstood the whole thing about TPersistent...
I do understand how `TPersistent` works for things like forms. A button has the form as owner, and the form has the Application as owner. Everything is then serialized as stream.
Now I see, that given `FChild := TXXX.Create(SomeOwner)`, after `FChild` reaches ARC=0, `SomeOwner._Release` is called, and as soon as `SomeOwner`'s ARC reaches zero, it will be destroyed, and IT shall release `FChild` in its destructor.
So, I will have to always use the owner-principle if I want to use `TPersistent`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use `TInterfacedObject`, but wrote `TInterfacedPersistent` instead, which does NOT manage the reference counting automatically.

Usually when I free an interfaced object, I'll always put an assertion one line before, to make sure that the object is actually an interfaced object.

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  intf: IXXX;
begin
  // create an interfaced object
  intf := TXXX.Create;

  // free an interfaced object
  if Assigned(intf) then
  begin
    assert(intf.InheritsFrom(TInterfacedObject));
    intf := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Note that `TSingletonImplementation` is yet another class that does not manage reference counting automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the blog link you posted, it's reasonable for some condidtions, especially when a component or a control that is owned by another component.

So you said that if there is a good reason not to use it. There's one:

"If your object is a component or a control that is owned by another component, then it is part of a different memory management system that is based in TComponent. Although some classes mix the object lifetime management approaches of TComponent and interface reference counting, this is very tricky to implement correctly"

[Not Using Reference Counting, the offical document said](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Not_Using_Reference_Counting)